# How to obtain (interacting) time-ordered correlation functions from the S-matrix - reverse of the LSZ formula?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, singularities, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

The LSZ formula shows how to obtain the S-matrix elements from the time-ordered correlation functions of the interacting fields.

I wonder if there is a reverse formula; that is, can we find the interacting correlation functions given that we have full information on the S-matrix?

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reversed [LSZ reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula) that starts from an $S$-matrix element and yields the corresponding correlation function, see e.g. eq. (7.42) in Peskin & Schroeder or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726228/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Strictly speaking this does not prove that it is not possible, since (sufficiently nice) analytic functions can be reconstructed given their pole structure.

Comment: I updated the answer.